# Get messy scraped data into data.frame in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am working on scraping a certain part of a perticular website, which looks like a table but isn't (unfortunately).

I use this code...

```
htmldoc <- read_html("http://www.wettportal.com/quotenvergleich/valuebets/")

data <- htmldoc %>% 
  html_node(xpath='//*[(@id = "datagrid_content")]') %>%
  html_text()

# alternative css selector: "#datagrid_content"
```

.. and get this kind of output:

```
Fussball | Schweden | Cup\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n08.06.2016\r\nTipp\r\nVQ\r\nBuchmacher\r\n100%\r\nProfit\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n19:00\r\nHuddinge IF - Enskede IK\r\n1 (DNB)\r\n1.73\r\nCoral\r\n1.50\r\n45.17%\r\n\r\n\r\n19:00\r\nHuddinge IF - Enskede IK\r\n1\r\n2.25\r\nCoral\r\n1.93\r\n35.00%\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n\r\n
```

As you can see, it is really messy and so far I have not been able to get it neatly into a data.frame.

Anyone got an idea of how to either

- select the object differently in order to obtain claner output from the start? (preferred)
- clean the data in a way so that it fits into a data.frame with columns like this:
  Sport | Country | Competition | Date | Time | Team1 | Team2 ...  ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there are some things which make this a bit complicated. I use different approach for webscraping but the code down there could help you out a bit

```
library(RCurl)
library(XML)
library(stringr)
library(tidyr)
url<-"http://www.wettportal.com/quotenvergleich/valuebets/"
url2<-getURL(url)
parsed<-htmlParse(url2,encoding = "UTF-8")

info1<-xpathSApply(parsed,"//div[@id='datagrid_content']//h2/span[1]",xmlValue)
date<-xpathSApply(parsed,"//th/time",xmlValue)
df<-data.frame(matrix(unlist(str_split(info1," . ",n = 3)),nrow=length(info1),byrow=T))
colnames(df)<-c("Sport","Country","Competition")
df<-cbind(df,date)
time<-xpathSApply(parsed,"//div[@id='datagrid_content']//tbody/tr/td[1]",xmlValue)
teams<-xpathSApply(parsed,"//div[@id='datagrid_content']//a/span",xmlValue)
ID<-1
for (i in 2:length(teams)){
    if (teams[i]==teams[i-1]){
        x<-max(ID,na.rm=TRUE)
    } else {
        x=max(ID,na.rm=TRUE)+1
    }
    ID<-c(ID,x)

}
df2<-cbind(teams,ID,time)
df$ID<-1:nrow(df)

final<-merge(df2,df)
final<-separate(final,col = teams,into=c("team1","team2"),sep =" - ")
final<-final[ ,c(5:8,4,2,3,1)]
```

[image]

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot! I actually hoped for a hint on possible "workaraounds" or whatever, but did not expect someone would go all the way. Additionally, thank you for showing me another way to web scraping in R ;-)

Comment: One more question though: What tool do you use to precisely find the Xpath of an element? I use selectorGadget and F12 in Chrome, but it does not show the same Xpath for the elements that you have in your code...

Comment: Well my approach is kind of different. With using chrome developer tools I locate a tag where required values are stored. E.G in case of teams vector I noticed that there are all within span tag. But then there might be many span tags in whole page so I used "a/span" to signal I want just span with a as a one level above tag. I tried to run the code but it returned some more data. So I limited selection with div as parent. So my usual approach is start with tag where values are and then add parent tags as needed not to specify absolute path

Answer (score 0):

I didn't you what you expected to get when executing your code, but it did exactly what you told it to do: it returns all the xmlvalue in the `div` with `id="datagrid_content"`.

- Now if you want a data.frame, you have to write a code so that it will give you a data.frame.
- The data is messy, you have to clean it. There is no automatic way. For example, you can get rid of some special characters, then split the data with |: `strsplit(gsub("\r|\n","",data)," | ")`
- Since data are in tables, you can also do:

  data <- htmldoc %>% 
  html_nodes(xpath='//*[@class="table-type-liga-1"]')%>%
  html_table()

You can get a list of data.frame.